# Android resources "best match" fallback logic

Tags: android, drawable, directory-structure, android-resources

I've read the docs about [Android Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) and I think I've understood the best-matching logic used by android to identify in which directory a particular resource should be searched first.. Supposing that *drawable-hdpi*, *drawable-en-port* and drawable-en* match the current device configuration, *drawable-en-port* is the best matching directory.. My question is, if a drawable is not found in *drawable-en-port*, does the system look directly in *drawable* or does it look in the second-best-match *drawable-en* and then in the third best match *drawable-hdpi* and so on until it reaches *drawable*? I suppose it works this way, but I did not find it explicitly said in the docs (unless I've read them too quickly and you will surely kill me :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it looks first in the `drawable-en`, then `drawable-hdpi` because language qualifier has higher precedence. If value was still not found `drawable` directory is searched. It is in accordance with: 
[How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

If `drawable-en` contains matching resource then `drawable-hdpi` and `drawable` would be eliminated based on step 4 of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I read the intro portion

```
assume the following drawable directories each contain different versions of the same images
```

In your example Android would ignore the drawable-en-port folder because it does not have that drawable name in it.  It would only look in the folders that have that drawable, therefore selecting the best matching folder.  It would only select 'drawable' if there were no folders with a matching configuration and image.