# Galaxy Note II - values-xhdpi or values-large?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the case I have both values-xhdpi and values-large resources with which one will the galaxy note II work with? I don't have a device for testing and the emulator only takes me so far.

Any idea?

Comment: put the values in both folder and print it in log-cat.I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [precedence table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2), `large` comes before `xhdpi`, therefore values from `values-large` will be used on the actual device.

An important note here, this happens **if the device actually declares itself as having a large screen**. However, devices are not very consistent about it, so I would consider adding resources to a folder like `sw600dp` because it is much more reliable. For more details read the link above and also check out how to use them in [best practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).

Comment: is it normal for two different Note II devices to use different layouts? I have a device that goes with xhdpi and another that goes with large. the xhdpi one is using a custom rom.. so maybe that's the case.

Comment: @aviran That's absolutely possible. That is exactly why I gave you the advice to use precise screen dimensions instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that Google's documentation naively assumes you don't want to support anything earlier than Android 3.2

Comment: @CoryTrese If you use qualifiers like `sw600dp`, that doesn't mean that the application won't run on anything earlier than Android 3.2 (read: on 2.3), it just won't be able to use these resources. But Android 2.3 doesn't support tablets anyway, so you won't have to worry about the screen size that much on earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a table of qualifer precedence:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2

> Android supports several configuration qualifiers and you can add multiple qualifiers to one directory name, by separating each qualifier with a dash. Table 2 lists the valid configuration qualifiers, in order of precedence—if you use multiple qualifiers for a resource directory, you must add them to the directory name in the order they are listed in the table.

Reading this part:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

It will find it in `-large` first and then ignore the `-xhdpi` one, so it looks like `-large` takes precedence over `-xhdpi`

Edit: someone else who agrees: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685580/833647

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed, that for Galaxy S3 and S4

```
values-sw360dp
```

works.